# Rotating views in Durandal

Tags: javascript, durandal

I am creating a leader board and need to rotate views that contain data that the team wants to see.  I am using WebAPI with Durandal.

I have a collection of strings that contain the name of each of the modules. This lives in Durandals app.js (called moduleList)

```
define(['./system', './viewEngine', './composition', './widget', './modalDialog', './events'], 
function(system, viewEngine, composition, widget, modalDialog, Events) {

var app = {
    title: 'Application',
    moduleList: [
        "petsSoldToday",
        "conversionRatioToday"
    ]
    .
    .
    .
};

Events.includeIn(app);

return app;
});
```

What I would like to do is call router.activate([moduleName]) on a loop so that all the modules will be displayed, one by one.

I have tried creating something simple in the shell.js activate function that basically calls

```
setTimeout(router.activate(current), 10000);
```

current being the next module in the list.  However, this causes a javascript error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I don't see anything in the stack that shows why either.  Honestly, I don't know what else to try.

How can this be done?  Can it be done at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your setTimeout function is executed immediately and that value is then passed to the setTimeout method (given you an error, because activate does not return a function).

You should put it inside a closure:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    router.activate(current)
}, 10000);
```

Comment: While I figured out before your answer, this is exactly how I did it. You get the answer.